How to remove the lock screen on Windows 10 Home?
I have Windows 10 home and I follow the steps here.
I restarted the PC after I did the steps and it still shows the lock screen

Can you provide a screenshot of what you believe is the Lock Screen?

I ask because with Windows 8+ there are two screens. One is the traditional Lock Screen (WinKey+L) the other is more of a standby screen which is shown right before the login screen. One I have can be disabled the other cannot, unless, you configured the system to automatically log into a user account.

The steps you followed should be included in the question. Please EDIT your question to add this info.

Immediately after a reboot there is the standard login screen, if that's the case you need to enable autologin: Autologin Windows 10 20H2
Instead, if it happens after the computer has been idle for a while it could be the screen saver, check the screensaver settings:

If none of these suggestions work, try here:
Prevent Windows 10 from Locking When Monitor Turns Off
or
How to disable Windows 10 lock screen password on IDLE only

i tried auto-login, i ran  netplwiz but it won't let me
